# Laravel ck editor 403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I do not know why i get this error because laravel ckeditor file upload workin on my local xampp server but when i put this to my live server i get this issue
403
Forbidden
Access to this resource on the server is denied

Please help

Comment: Make sure the directory you are uploading to has write access.

Comment: yes permission is 0777 for storage folder but not working

Comment: vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/kcfinder change the permission 755
solved

Comment: not solved this issue yet, any suggestion???